# Formatting statements within functions - rules?

Tags: haskell

Consider:

```
myFunction :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a]
myFunction v1 v2 = statement_1.. $ statement_2... $ statement_3...
```

vs

```
myFunction :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> [a]
myFunction v1 v2 = statement_1 result_1 result_2
    where
      result_2 = statement_2
      result_3 = statement_3
```

Is there a rule of thumb as to which format is preferred in Haskell? Are there any specific rules as to when to use each version?

Comment: I think the latter is more readable. I also make *many* functions in imperative languages, if it'll result in immediately understandable and well-named functions. However, this question is too opinion-based to result in good answers.

Comment: I use the latter if I can assign meaningful names to the `result_i` variables. Otherwise I tend to use the first form, possibly on multiple lines, and often using `.` instead of `$` for all but the last one.

Comment: Just a semantic note: Haskell doesn't have statements that can occur in the body of a function, only expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, these aren't actually equivalent. `f $ x $ y` is parsed as `f $ (x $ y)` (because `infixr 0 $`), hence you'd actually need to write the first version as

```
myFunction v1 v2 = (statement_1.. $ statement_2...) $ statement_3...
```

or, if `statement_1` is actually just a single symbol, I'd actually prefer

```
myFunction v1 v2 = statement_1 (statement_2...) (statement_3...)
```

Really, your question is whether it makes sense to give these intermediate results names of their own. Well, that's a question that has little to do with Haskell – it can apply to most programming languages, though few give you the possibility to write as much in a single expression as Haskell does. It can only be answered as: give them names if it makes the code easier to understand. Perhaps it's hard to see what `statement_2 ...` is supposed to be good for, but a “single-word comment” would clear it up? Well, then give it a name! If instead it's just a short expression and it's clear what it means anyway, I wouldn't bother.

Note that in some cases, it may affect performance (even complexity) whether or not you define something as a named entity. For example, if `result_1` is a lengthy computation that does not depend on `v2`, it makes sense to write it this way:

```
myFunction v1 = \v2 -> statement_1 result_1 $ statement_3..
 where result_1 = statement_2
```

This allows you to apply the function partially, to only the `v1` argument, and thus share a lot of the computational effort for multiple calls over `v2`, e.g. with `map (myFunction v1₀) listOfV2s`.